# Why is Log4j2 throwing an error in Windows bash console

Tags: java, windows, bash, log4j2

Good morning,

using log4j2 in my project (see below the configuration) running it, everything went ok in Eclipse. Then building the jar and executing it in a bash Windows, I get an error thrown regarding the "Console Appender". After investigation, it works in other shells (like git bash), my question here is about if this behavior is documented somewhere ?(because after googling it a lot, I did not find anything relevant).

My log4j2.properties:

```
   name=PropertiesConfig
   property.directory = ./logs
   appenders = console, file, testFile

   appender.console.type = Console
   appender.console.target =SYSTEM_OUT
   appender.console.name = STDOUT
   appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
   appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} line %L - %msg%n

   appender.file.type = File
   appender.file.append = false
   appender.file.name = LOGFILE
   appender.file.fileName=${directory}/neoswitcher-${date:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.log
   appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
   appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

   appender.testFile.type = File
   appender.testFile.append = false
   appender.testFile.name = LOGTestFILE
   appender.testFile.fileName=${directory}/test-suite-${date:yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}.log
   appender.testFile.layout.type=PatternLayout
   appender.testFile.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

   loggers=file
   logger.file.name=org.test.controller.core
   logger.file.level = info
   logger.file.appenderRefs = file
   logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

   loggers=file
   logger.testFile.name=org.simpleperftests.core;
   logger.testFile.level = info
   logger.testFile.appenderRefs = testFile
   logger.testFile.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGTestFILE

   rootLogger.level = info
   rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout, file, testFile
   rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
   rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
   rootLogger.appenderRef.testFile.ref = LOGTestFILE
```

And here the error occuring in the MS-DOS console:

```
2017-02-24 10:55:11,994 main ERROR Unable to inject fields into builder class for plugin type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender, element Cons
ole. java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: sun.stdout.encoding
        at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.getCharsetProperty(PropertiesUtil.java:146)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.getCharsetProperty(PropertiesUtil.java:134)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Target.getCharset(ConsoleAppender.java:85)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Target$1.getDefaultCharset(ConsoleAppender.java:71)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder.build(ConsoleAppender.java:218)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender$Builder.build(ConsoleAppender.java:185)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:537)
        at org.test.controller.core.App.<clinit>(App.java:14)

2017-02-24 10:55:12,001 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console. java.lang.
IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:224)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:130)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:537)
        at org.test.controller.core.App.<clinit>(App.java:14)

2017-02-24 10:55:12,012 main ERROR Null object returned for Console in Appenders.
2017-02-24 10:55:12,012 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "STDOUT" for logger config "root"
```

**Edit**: It actually works fine on Linux with that version

Comment: "sun.stdout.encoding" is not a charset. Did you check your configuration?

Comment: I would assume that's the charset that log4j2 detects from the Windows bash console. I don't know of any way to modify the charset of the Windows bash (especially that I don't have admin rights on this machine)

Comment: This reminds me of a similar issue that came up on the Log4j2 mailing list or one of the JIRA tickets. Can you raise your issue there?

Comment: Of course, I just wanted to have some experts' advice (since I only started recently using it) on the topic. Thanks

Comment: It's done here, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1825, I'll post an answer when it is resolved.

Comment: FWIW, in your example above you have loggers=file declared twice. I beleive you meant to have loggers=file, testFile

Comment: You're completely right, it was not my final properties file though (I made a lot of modifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing with the snapshot release (version 2.8.1-SNAPSHOT), the bug is fixed.

The snapshot versions for log4j2 are available at this repository: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/

Answer (score 1):

Using version 2.8.1 instead of 2.8.0 seemed to resolved the issue for me

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Correct at the time of my answer 2.8.1 wasn't released yet

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue in Windows command promt. I tried in Git Bash and it is working fine as usual.

So, install Git Bash and try in Git Bash, it should work fine.